# SIteCore - multisite - displaying page from wrong site

Tags: sitecore

We have a multisite SiteCore setup with 2 sites within the same .Net solution.

This works by setting the rootPath property on a Site Definition in web.config to limit the site to part of the SiteCore folder structure.

This works well apart from when pages are created with the same name as in the other site then it's serving content from the other site! We have inherited a fair bit of custom code in this solution form the other site so this may be the cause but dont know what Im looking for ...

Thanks

Comment: Post your site definitions please

Answer (score 0):

How are you referencing the sites?  Do they each have their own host name?  Do you have the "`hostName`" property set for the site node in the Site Defintion?

I will assume that you are not referring to them this way and instead, the sites are using the "`virtualFolder`" property.  If both sites have the same default value of "`/`" for `virtualFolder`, attempting to get to either site will result in Sitecore rendering the first site that it matches on, which would be the site listed first.

Try putting the actual site name for "`virtualFolder`" and "`physicalFolder`" (e.g. "Site1" and "Site2", respectively).  Then you can address your sites as http://yourserver.com/Site1 and http://yourserver.com/Site2.  The "`virtualFolder`" will match first and render the correct site.

See [Configuring Sites in the web.config](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Configuring%20Sites%20in%20web,-d-,config%20File.aspx) File on SDN for additional information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Craig, We are using the first approach ... each site has their own host name

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is happening in this case because of a System alias that is redirecting for a subset of pages